# SQL. How to reference a composite primary key Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, composite-primary-key

I have two parent tables: `Treatment` and `Visit`.

Treatment table:

```
 create table Treatment (
    TreatCode CHAR(6) constraint cTreatCodeNN not null,
    Name VARCHAR2(20),
    constraint cTreatCodePK primary key (TreatCode),
    );
```

Visit table:

```
create table Visit (
SlotNum NUMBER(2),
DateVisit DATE,
ActualArrivalTime DATE,
constraint cVisitSlotDatePK primary key (SlotNum, DateVisit)
);
```

Now I try to create a child table:

```
create table Visit_Treat (
TreatCode constraint cTreatCodeFK references Treatment(TreatCode),
SlotNum constraint cSlotNumFK references Visit(SlotNum),
DateVisit constraint cDateFK references Visit(DateVisit),
constraint cVisitTreatPK primary key (SlotNum, TreatCode, DateVisit)
);
```

Everything executes fine till the 3 line. Starting from the 3rd line, i.e. `SlotNum constraint ...` there is a message: `no matching unique or primary key`. There was already a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602099/oracle-composite-primary-key-foreign-key-question), but i did not quite get the logic to apply in my case. I reference each column one by one, and it works for the `Treatment` table parent.  How should i correct reference `Visit` table parent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 CONSTRAINT fk_column
 FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
 REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
```

in your case

```
create table Visit_Treat (
TreatCode CHAR(6) constraint cTreatCodeFK references Treatment(TreatCode),
SlotNum NUMBER(2),
DateVisit DATE,
constraint cVisitTreatPK primary key (SlotNum, TreatCode, DateVisit),
constraint fk_slotnumDatevisit FOREIGN KEY(SlotNum,DateVisit) 
references Visit(SlotNum,DateVisit)
);
```

Comment: This might or might not be the solution, since we don't know what is actually right & what is wrong in the code, and it doesn't address what (combinations of) declarations should be used in what circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

A foreign key must reference the primary key of the parent table - the *entire* primary key. In your case, the `Visit` table's primary key is `SlotNum, DateVisit` but the foreign key from `Visit_Treat` only references `SlotNum`.

You have two good options:

1. Add a `DateVisit` column to `Visit_Treat` and have the foreign key be `SlotNum, DateVisit`, referencing `SlotNum, DateVisit` in `Visit`.
2. Create a non-business primary key on `Visit` (for example a column named `VisitID` of type `NUMBER`, fed by a sequence), add a `VisitID` column to `Visit_Treat`, and make that the foreign key.

And two bad options:

1. Change the `Visit` primary key to be only `SlotNum` so your `Visit_Treat` foreign key will work. This probably isn't what you want.
2. Don't use a foreign key. I don't recommend this option. If you're having trouble setting up a foreign key that you know should exist, it generally means a design problem.

Comment: Your first sentence is not correct. An SQL FK references a declared PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL. (More or less a superkey--and not necessarily a minimal/irreducible one, ie a CK.) Since either of those might contain a smaller one or the other, a FK has to reference all of one, but not necessarily all of any particular one, including a PK. You sort of indirectly address this in bad option 1. Although "bad option" seems a misnomer since that is just a case where the design is wrong but the FK is right.

Comment: can I see example syntax?  I'm stuck on this where I have a composite primary key in table Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom) and have a foreign key in table Guest called guestNo that I want referencing guestNo in Booking.

Comment: @mLstudent if the FK really references `Booking` then I don't know how to pull that off. But I'm probably misunderstanding your question. Could you post this as a separate question, and include the table structures? There will be plenty of people who can answer.